# JavaScript: how to get img and div elements using getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript

I have a tree structure as follows:

```
<ul id="theul275">
  <li>
    <div id="red"></div>
    <img id="green" />
    <script></script>
    <div id="blue"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

There are multiple UL's likes this on my page each with a different id. I am getting each UL by doing this:

```
var child = document.getElementById('theul' + id).getElementsByTagName('*');
```

the problem is, I only want to get the children of each ul which are either div's or img's.
Is there a way to get elements by multiple tag names?

I really appreciate any help because I am kind of new to JavaScript! Thanks!

Comment: You should definitely be using `element.childNodes` instead of `element.getElementsByTagName` for this.

Comment: @Matt: childNodes only return direct decedents, not child of childs. But you can of course use it in a iterate function.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914783/javascript-nodelist/914995#914995

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/a/2317716/820013

document.querySelectorAll("div, img");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0, l = child.length; i < l; i++)
{
    if (child[i].nodeName == 'DIV' || child[i].nodeName == 'IMG')
    {
          //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what browsers you may to support, you could use the CSS selector interface.

```
document.getElementById('theul275').querySelectorAll('div, img');
```

Or use a library. There are plenty of options out there. I am familiar with two,

MooTools

```
$('theul275').getElements('div, img');
```

jQuery

```
$('#theul275').find('div, img');
```

Or get a reference to the `li` node, and loop through each node and check if the nodeName is `DIV` or `IMG`.

Comment: This is the best answer, imo.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a iterative method for this.

```
var elemArray = document.getElementById('theul' + id).childNodes,
    getChildByNodeName = function (elem, pattern) {
        var childCollection = [],
            re = new RegExp(pattern, 'g'),
            getChild = function (elements) {
                var childs = elements.childNodes,
                    i = 0;

                if (childs) {
                    getChild(childs);
                    for (i = 0; i < childs.length; i += 1) {
                        if (childs[i].nodeName.match(pattern)) {
                            childCollection.push(childs[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

         getChild(elem);
         return childCollection;
     } 

var childs2 = getChildByNodeName(elemArray, '^(DIV|IMG)$'); // array of match elements
```

And just change the pattern (`'^(DIV|IMG)$'`) to suite your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, try

```
var child = $("#theul" + id).find("div,img");
```

Otherwise, see [JavaScript NodeList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914783/javascript-nodelist/914995#914995).