# Combining arrays returned by getElementsByWhatever

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to get all the form elements within a specific div, and combine them into a single array using the array concat() method:

```
var div_id = 'some_div_id'; // in real life this is passed as a function parameter

var child_inputs = document.getElementById(div_id).getElementsByTagName('input');
var child_textareas = document.getElementById(div_id).getElementsByTagName('textarea');
var child_selects = document.getElementById(div_id).getElementsByTagName('select');

var field_elements = child_inputs.concat(child_textareas, child_selects); // this doesnt work?
```

However the script fails at the last line I'm not sure why.  I can't use .childNodes because the div_id being passed is not the direct parent.

Comment: Array structures must be identical to use concat. These element selectors produce results that are not. These are not simple lists - they're objects.

Comment: In addition see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735067/how-to-convert-a-dom-node-list-to-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: Also see: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914783/javascript-nodelist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914783/javascript-nodelist)

Comment: You could: `var elems = document.getElementById( div_id ).querySelectorAll( 'input, textarea, select' );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList` not an array, so you can't use `concat`.

If you want to "transform" the nodeList into an array you could call slice from the Array protype chain:

```
var div_id = 'some_div_id',
    divIdElement = document.getElementById(div_id); //cache the element

var getArrayFromTag = function(tagname) {
     //get the NodeList and transform it into an array
     return Array.prototype.slice.call(divIdElement.getElementsByTagName(tagname));
}

//Get the arrays
var child_inputs = getArrayFromTag('input');
var child_textareas = getArrayFromTag ('textarea');
var child_selects = getArrayFromTag ('select');

//use concat
var field_elements = child_inputs.concat(child_textareas, child_selects);
```

Answer (score 1):

Those methods don't return an Array.  Instead it's a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList) or perhaps an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCollection).  (See [the note under Syntax.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName#Syntax))

You might [loop over each nodelist](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList#Example) and form an array of them 'by hand'.