# Getting different html elements in a common variable

Tags: javascript, html

Right now i am getting elements from form using getelementTagname in two differenet variables.But now i want to join them so that i can access them in a single variable.concat and join are not working , any suggestions ?

My code :-

```
var inputsi = frm.getElementsByTagName("input");
var inputst = frm.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
```

now i want to get them in a single variable by joining .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a [host object](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-4.3.8). Though the elements in that object can be accessed like an array, it is not an actual array. so concat and append won't work.

use jQuery for getting elements:

```
var elements = $("input, textarea"); // return you all the textareas and inputs in a single variable
```

or use `for` loop to copy all elements from both variables into a new array.

Comment: @Nemoy.....don't want to use jquery .thanks for the help.......found the sotution in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914783/javascript-nodelist

Comment: Ya i suggested to use jquery or a for loop to copy all elements.

Comment: @Nemoya—[getElementsByTagName](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094) returns a [NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177), which is a [host](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-4.3.8) object, not a [native](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-4.3.6) object.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you join two string by simply adding them, e.g `var stringC = stringA + stringB`. What you have there in your code are no strings yet. `frm.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value` gets you the information as a string.

Comment: @Amberlamps..it gives the length as null of variables