# Which is the best way to add the two document element's array into one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, getelementsbyname

```
var b = document.getElementsByName("button");
var l = document.getElementsByName("link");
```

Which is the best way to add the content of these two arrays into one? 
I don't want to use for loop

Comment: The same - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript NodeList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914783/javascript-nodelist)

Comment: Those are not arrays, they're `NodeList` objects. See the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/914995/825789) to the question I linked as a dupe (that solution does not involve a for loop)

Comment: Define your criteria for "best".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.slice.call()` to turn the `nodeLists` into real arrays and then use array operations on them to combine them

```
var b = document.getElementsByName("button");
var l = document.getElementsByName("link");
// make both nodeLists into real arrays
var copyB = Array.prototype.slice.call(b, 0);
var copyL = Array.prototype.slice.call(l, 0);
var combined = copyB.concat(copyL);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vZ5tb/

Or, a little briefer version:

```
var copyB = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByName("button"), 0);
var copyL = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByName("link"), 0);
var combined = copyB.concat(copyL);
```

Comment: Why answering this instead of closing the question as a dupe? Question and answer are nearly identical to the ones I linked to.