# getElementsByTagName: How to select more than one type of tag?

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop inside which I check to see if the current element being iterated has any `a` tags or `form` tags inside of it and if so I do some stuff to them. Anyway I can check either or like so:

```
var form_or_a_tag = elem[i].getElementsByTagName('a');
var form_or_a_tag = elem[i].getElementsByTagName('form');
```

But how can I combine them?

these all fail:

```
var form_or_a_tag = elem[i].getElementsByTagName('a form');
var form_or_a_tag = elem[i].getElementsByTagName('a, form');
var form_or_a_tag = elem[i].getElementsByTagName('a') || elem[i].getElementsByTagName('form');
```

Basically I would like to store in the variable `form_or_a_tag` all `form` or `a` tags that reside in the element currently being iterated.

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: You could just concat the two arrays: `a_tags.concat(form_tags)`

Comment: @lethal-guitar: `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList` not an array, so it doesn't have `concat`.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat is there anyway to merge nodelists? EDIT: looks like there is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914783/javascript-nodelist. This worked for me.

Comment: @JakeRow123: You can try `querySelectorAll` (like in my answer).

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat Oh, good to know. Rarely using plain JS..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might work:

```
var nodelist_a    = elem[i].getElementsByTagName('a');         // NodeList
var nodelist_form = elem[i].getElementsByTagName('form');      // NodeList

var array_a       = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodelist_a);    // Array
var array_form    = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodelist_form); // Array

var array_both    = array_a.concat(array_form);                // Array
```

Note that the result is no longer a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList) but an Array; however each item is a [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `querySelectorAll`.

```
var form_or_a_tag = elem[i].querySelectorAll('a, form');
```

Comment: Note that not all browsers support this. I'll let you think about what browser I mean.

Comment: Any browser worth using supports this: http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelectorAll

Comment: @PeeHaa: Isn't `a, form` a CSS2 selector?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this function supports this feature. AFAIK you can use only getElementsByTagName("*") wildcard to select all nodes. You can try some library like Sizzle to use CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

If sequence of nodes is important, here is pure Javascript solution:

```
var getNodesInTreeByNodeName = function (node, /*Array of Strings*/ allowed_node_names)
{
    var childCollection = [];
    var getTreeNodes = function (tree_root)
    {
        if (allowed_node_names.indexOf(tree_root.nodeName) > -1)
            childCollection.push(tree_root);
        var childs = tree_root.childNodes;
        if (childs)
            for (var i=0, childs_length=childs.length ; i<childs_length ; i++)
                getTreeNodes(childs[i]);
    };
    getTreeNodes(node);
    return childCollection;
};
```

Example of use:

```
    var node_types = ["A","FORM"];
    var nodes = getNodesInTreeByNodeName(window.document, wanted_nodes);
```