# How to append elements to the parent elements extracted by getElementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Below is my JSP code,

```
<%
    while(resultSet1.next()){
                        out.println("<p class='comm'>");
                        out.println(resultSet1.getString("answer_content"));
                        out.println("</p>");

                    }
%>
```

Below is the script I have used,

```
<script>

            $( document ).ready(function() {

                var par = document.getElementsByClassName("comm");

                var insert = document.createElement("form");
                insert.setAttribute("action","ForumSubmitCommentController");

                var text = document.createElement("input");
                text.setAttribute("type","text");
                text.setAttribute("name","comm_text");
                text.setAttribute("id","comm_text");
                insert.appendChild(text);

                var comm_submit = document.createElement("input");
                comm_submit.setAttribute("type","submit");
                comm_submit.setAttribute("value","Comment");
                insert.appendChild(comm_submit);

                par.appendChild(insert);

           });

        </script>
```

I'am expecting to get a form attached to all the 'p' elements with "class='comm'" but I'm getting none. So can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should consider to use jQuery all the way through. It will make things easier. getElementsByClassName returns a **list** of elements. This list doesn't have a method appendChild. You have select a specific element from the list to which you want to append the new element.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for pointing out man now I have tried the code as shown by Arun and it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `par` is an array, so doesn't have appendChild method

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.comm').each(function () {
        var insert = document.createElement("form");
        insert.setAttribute("action", "ForumSubmitCommentController");

        var text = document.createElement("input");
        text.setAttribute("type", "text");
        text.setAttribute("name", "comm_text");
        text.setAttribute("id", "comm_text");
        insert.appendChild(text);

        var comm_submit = document.createElement("input");
        comm_submit.setAttribute("type", "submit");
        comm_submit.setAttribute("value", "Comment");
        insert.appendChild(comm_submit);

        this.appendChild(insert);

    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v3Nzc/)

---

But a easier way to do it is to use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var form = '<form action="ForumSubmitCommentController"><input type="text" name="comm_text" id="comm_text"><input type="submit" value="Comment"></form>';

    $('.comm').append(form)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BLwwx/)

Answer (score 2):

This kind of DOM manipulations is very basic stuff when you use some library (like jQuery) but sometimes can be hard or at least verbose with plain old DOM API.

For example [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). It is array-like collection of elements found. You need to traverse it in some way to put your form to all of the elements.

For example:

```
nodesList = document.getElementsByClassName("helloworld");
for(var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    var node = nodeList[i];
    // create form etc...
    node.appendChild(form);
}
```

Notice that `HTMLCollection` does not even provide `forEach` method - we have to use plain for-loop or convert it to `Array` first (e.g. by using hacks like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/914995/539686)). And you must create your form node (or use `cloneNode`) before every [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild), because each DOM node is unique and `appendChild` only moves it to desire location.

jQuery and other libraries do that behind the scene, hiding complexities and making your code more readable. I suggest you to learn DOM API only to get the understanding about how things really work. In real projects just stick with jQuery, learn it and use it for all manipulations.